# What does this query mean with keywords like sha, CONCAT and X?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm in a class where we have to type a query like this:

```
SELECT sha1(CONCAT(name,age)) AS X FROM Ages ORDER BY X
```

I don't understand what this means. What does this query actually say?

I understand CONCAT means joining name and age. This creates a sha? Does the X mean anything significant?

I'm new to queries, and I'm trying to define all the different types for my notes and understanding so I can read them. If anyone can help translate this, I would appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: It's generating the [`SHA-1` hash](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha1) of the `Name` and `Age` concatenated together.  The `X` is just the column alias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In english, it says:

1. Take the `name` and `age` of each record from the `Ages` table.
2. Concatenate the `name` and `age` together.
3. Take the SHA-1 Hash of that concatenated value and call it "X"
4. When complete, then order the results by the Hashed concatenated value (a.k.a "X").

Comment: This is awesome. Totally makes sense the way you laid this out here. Thank you @JNevill!